# Laspy LAZ exported files with extra dimensions and QGIS name mangling

Tags: qgis, las, laspy, laz, potree

I'm writing a LAZ file with laspy, and I include some extra dimensions named bx, by, bz and b. They are all np.float64 (I used the version 1.4 and point format 3).

The file is properly created but when importing it to QGIS the extra dimensions names are mangled: when I look a the details of a point, I can see that the values for bx and by have been swaped, and that the values for bz and b have been swaped.

I converted the same LAZ file to a potree compatible file, and I loaded it in a potree web page. The values were not mangled, so that leads me to think that it is an issue with QGIS specifically.

Did you encounter this issue of extra dimensions being mixed up ? Is it a strange interaction between QGIS and laspy ?